# Parsing the line doesnt work as intended in locally-developed shell

Tags: c

I try to create a Linux shell and I encounter a problem , I read the user input , store it in an array of strings , tokenize it and whatever condition I have args[0] is never true. Here's the code

```
void shell_loop(void)
{
    char *line;
    char **args;
    int status;

    do
    {
        printf("%s","sh1>");
        line=read_line();
        args=parse_line(line);
        status=execute_arguements(args);
    } while(status);
}

char * read_line(void)
{
    char * line=NULL;
    int bufferSize=MAX_SIZE;
    getline(&line,&bufferSize,stdin);
    return line;
}

char ** parse_line(char * line)
{
    int position=0;
    char ** tokens=malloc(MAX_SIZE*sizeof(char*));
    char * token;

    if(!tokens)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    token=strtok(line," ");

    while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;
    token=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    tokens[position] = NULL;
    return tokens;
}

int execute_arguements(char ** args)
{
    if (args[0] == NULL)
    {
    return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n",args[0]);

    if(args[0]=="exit" || args[0]=="^D")
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  return 1;

}
```

Whatever condition I write in the if statements it doesn't work , for example if I write exit or Ctrl+D nothing happens because the if is never true . If I just press enter args[0]==NULL is false, if I press exit args[0]=="exit"is false even though prinf("%s",args[0]) prints exit for example.Does anyone has any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Still , I change the code to if(strcmp(args[0],"exit")==0 || strcmp(args[0],"^D")==0)
 {
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

Comment: and when I write exit or press Control+D nothing happens, the condition is still false

Comment: This isn't a "Linux shell" in any meaningful sense. It's your own hand-built C program; it didn't come with any Linux distribution at all, and doesn't comply with the POSIX sh standard re: how compliant shells are obliged to behave.

Comment: Also, please review the guidance on building a [mcve]. We ask that questions that incorporate code here have the *smallest possible code* that someone else can run to see a problem themselves, with all components unrelated to that specific problem excluded from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see from comments that you've taken user3121023's advice to use `strcmp()` rather than '==' for string comparisons.  That's the first issue.

You can't test for end-of-input by comparing with `control-D`.  `Control-D` is a way the user can (depending on options) signal end of file on input.  But that character is not conveyed as part of the input; instead the input stream is closed.  Instead  you need to check for end-of-file in the call to `getline()` and restructure the rest accordingly.

Most likely, the reason `strcmp()` is not matching is because the input returned by `getline` ends with a newline character.  Your `read_line()` function should probably strip any newline from the end of the line.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html